# NSubstitute, DbContext and a strange issue when trying to write a test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dbcontext, nsubstitute

I have a nice extension method for mocking a **DbSet**:

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static DbSet<T> ToDbSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data) where T : class
    {
        var queryData = data.AsQueryable();
        var dbSet = Substitute.For<DbSet<T>, IQueryable<T>>();
        ((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).Provider.Returns(queryData.Provider);
        ((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).Expression.Returns(queryData.Expression);
        ((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).ElementType.Returns(queryData.ElementType);
        ((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).GetEnumerator().Returns(queryData.GetEnumerator());

        return dbSet;
    }
}
```

Which I am trying to use in a context file like this:

```
public class DatabaseContextContext<T> where T: DatabaseContextContext<T>
{
    public DatabaseContext DatabaseContext;
    protected DatabaseContextContext()
    {
        DatabaseContext = Substitute.For<DatabaseContext>();
    }

    public T WhenListSucceeds<TEntity>(IList<TEntity> data) where TEntity : class
    {
        var dbSet = data.ToDbSet();
        DatabaseContext.Set<TEntity>().Returns(dbSet);

        return (T)this;
    }

    public T WhenGetSucceeds<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        var dbSet = new List<TEntity> { entity }.ToDbSet();
        DatabaseContext.Set<TEntity>().Returns(dbSet);

        return (T)this;
    }
}
```

When I run my test on this method, it fails:

```
public ActionResult<List<Formula>> ListFormulas(int id) =>
    Ok(_databaseContext.Formulas.Where(m => m.AttributeId.Equals(id)).ToList());
```

with this error message:

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy_3' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model'.

So I tried to break it down a bit.
First, I changed my method to this:

```
public ActionResult<List<Formula>> ListFormulas(int id)
{
    var s = _databaseContext.Formulas;
    var x = _databaseContext.Formulas.ToList();
    var t = _databaseContext.Formulas.Where(m => m.AttributeId.Equals(id)).ToList();

    return Ok(t);
}
```

But when debugging, the code was not getting past the `ToList()` method. I was still getting the same issue. So I have changed my code to this:

```
public ActionResult<List<Formula>> ListFormulas(int id)
{
    var p = _databaseContext.Set<Formula>();
    var q = p.ToList();


    var s = _databaseContext.Formulas;
    var x = _databaseContext.Formulas.ToList();
    var t = _databaseContext.Formulas.Where(m => m.AttributeId.Equals(id)).ToList();

    return Ok(t);
}
```

The first 3 lines of code work, but as soon as it get's to the line `var x = _databaseContext.Formulas.ToList();` it fails.
Does anyone have any idea why?

Here is the test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ListShould
{
    [Test]
    public void ReturnList()
    {
        // Assemble
        var services = GenericOrderProviderContext.GivenServices();
        var provider = services.WhenCreateOrderProvider();

        services.DatabaseContext.Attributes = new List<Attribute>().ToDbSet();
        services.DatabaseContext.Set<Attribute>().ReturnsForAnyArgs(_ => new List<Attribute>().ToDbSet());

        // Act
        var result = provider.List();

        // Assert
        result.Failure.Should().BeFalse();
        result.Result.Count().Should().Be(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Better off using in-memory database.

Comment: Also `DatabaseContext.Set<TEntity>().Returns(dbSet)` will only work when `.Set<TEntity>()` is invoked. in your example, when `_databaseContext.Formulas` is unknown to the mock

Comment: I thought that too, but I hard coded the dbSet to formulas and still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your error when the db context `.Formulas` property wasn't configured. If you're using both `.Set<Formula>()` and `.Formulas` you'll need to configure both.

I did notice that your set up for the db set enumerator

```
((IQueryable<T>)dbSet).GetEnumerator().Returns(queryData.GetEnumerator());
```

cause some behaviour that I've seen before where only the first ToList() invocation returns a result. If you get that, you may need to reset the enumerator or use the `Func<CallInfo, IEnumerator<Formula>>` `Returns` overload.

Comment: I already do set both and my first call **.ToList()** is in that test, so it should not be an issue with `GetEnumerator`

Comment: Pop up a minimum reproducible example and I'll have another look